# Which damp foil / vapor barrier shall I use when insulating?

Tags: insulation

I'm insulating using rockwool between two floors and wondering which foil shall I use on the small section that faces the outer wall?

Its a old poorly insulated house from 1930 with brick walls. Also, how can I attach the vapor barrier? Most recommend using staples or tape, but its really hard to access the small space. [image]

Comment: Maybe it's because I'm not an insulation expert, but what is the "foil" for? Is it to be a vapor barrier? Something else?

Comment: @FreeMan, indeed vapor barrier, much better to use that instead of the word foil.